# discord.py custom help message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm making a bot for discord and I want to have a custom help-message. I tried:

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    member = ctx.author
    await ctx.send(member, "test successful")

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

It's supposed to send a private message to the user and send them whatever. But when I enter `!help` the bot doesn't even react to the message.

Comment: Have you passed a `member`? You are saying that after running `!help` nothing happens, this is because you did not pass a `member`, I guess.

Comment: @Dominik It's actually a mistake I did while writing the question, fixed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defining your `bot`, the default is to have an automatic help command. `commands.Bot` has a keyword parameter `help_command` that you can set to `None` to make sure that the automatic help command is turned off. Also, to send a direct message to someone, you have to use `user.send()`. Your original command also required you to mention the user, as it took a `Member` as an argument. I'm not sure if that was what you want, but I wouldn't think so.

Here's what I would do:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!",help_command=None)
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    await ctx.author.send("test successful")
```

Edit: clarity in my explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Sending a message only has one positional argument (the message itself) and options. In order to send a DM message, you will need to send on the member class instead.

```py
await member.send("test successful")
```